# How can I create this bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, journal

So it looks exactly like the older JF-articles:

link: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.sty

[image]

Comment: {jf }  is the Journal of Finance bibliography style - a specific journal in the area of finance

Comment: When was the book published? Around 1985? The chances it was produced with BibTeX are vanishingly small since BibTeX was only released in 1985, and I doubt that the *Journal of Finance* was an early adopter.  There is also the problem that not every possible bibliographical style has a corresponding BibTeX style. (In my areas of study, e.g., there are virtually none!)

Comment: This was an article published in 1984- JF

Comment: link: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.sty

Comment: Then it cannot be BibTeX, can it?

Comment: Although maybe it was later than 1984? http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/.

Answer (score 2):

The [very site you link](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.sty) answers your question almost immediately. It is, in fact, hard to miss it. It has a [zip file](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/zip/texintro.zip) and, in case you can't be bothered to download it, it also has a [direct link to the `.bst`](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.bst).