# Where can I find this bibliography style 2?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, jabref

Any way someone can find this (article was published in 1986 Journal of Finance) ? Make it ? Or otherwise?

[image: The best bibliography style]

Comment: Looks like IEEE.  Take a look [`here`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en)

Comment: This Is not about the "line" but the style, so it has nothing to do with that answer. It looks like IEEE but there are a lot of differences aswell

Comment: It woud be helpfu to know the style's name. What journal is it? Does this journal has a style handbook to recreate it?

Comment: Journal of Finance : It does not have anything on its website, like I have found for many other finance journals, unfortunately.

Comment: You really provide very little information. How about creating a base document that we can use as a point of departure for recreating this?

Comment: Rather than search for an existing bibliography style file that just happens to implement all formatting requirements, you may want to look into using the `makebst` utility -- part of the [custom-bib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package -- to create a bespoke bibliography style from scratch. Type `texdoc custom-bib` at a command prompt to bring up the package's user guide.

Comment: Sorry if I've missed something, but isn't this the same style you asked about before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291703/how-can-i-creat-this-biblography-style ?

Comment: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/

Comment: Please do not SHOUT. Shouting at people because they fail to answer poor questions only irritates them further. It would be a lot easier, I would have thought, to simply download the `.bst` file provided on the very site which you link to. I hope you're not doing research for the journal.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have anything? Maybe. But the [site linked](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.sty) in [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291703/how-can-i-creat-this-biblography-style) certainly does. It has a [zip file](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/zip/texintro.zip) and, in case you can't be bothered to download it, it also has a [direct link to the `.bst`](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.bst).